# Close search form if anywhere else on page is clicked besides the visible form

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my search icon is clicked, I want to fade in my search form and add focus. If anywhere on the page other than the form is clicked while the form is open, I want to make the form fade out. Here is my code. Currently, the form hides even when the form is clicked:

```
<form class="form-inline align-middle d-none d-md-inline-block" action="/" role="search">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="s" placeholder="type and tap enter" aria-label="search" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">
</form>

var searchForm = $( '.navbar form' );

// Navbar Search Toggle, hide nav menu if open
$( '.search-icon-container' ).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    searchForm.toggleClass( 'visible' );
    $( '.navbar form input' ).focus();
    $( '.navbar-collapse' ).removeClass( 'show' );
});

// Close search bar if anywhere else in the document is clicked other than the form
$("body:not('.navbar form')").on( 'click', function() {
    if( searchForm.hasClass( 'visible' ) ) {
        searchForm.toggleClass( 'visible' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put an event listener on all body elements that aren't a form inside a .navbar. Clicking inside the form will still bubble up to the body. Instead, listen for a click on the body, then check if the click was within your form:

```
$("body").on( 'click', function(e) {
        if( !$(e.target).closest('form.form-inline').length && archForm.hasClass('visible') ) {
            searchForm.toggleClass( 'visible' );
        }
    });
```

You could also used a whole-screen fixed element underneath your form but over the rest of the body, and listen for a click on that.